# How to sign using windows crypto API that can be verified with OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, ecdsa, webcrypto-api, webauthn

I am using crypto API to sign and send it to the webserver that uses open SSL to verify the signature. The signature verifies successfully using Windows crypto API but getting an error while verification with open SSL from the server end.

Error:

> ECDsa signature not a valid DER sequence

Signing function:

```
  public async sign(data: Uint8Array): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.privateKey) {
        throw new Error('no private key available for signing');
    }
    return window.crypto.subtle.sign(
        this.getKeyParams(),
        this.privateKey,
        data,
    );
}

private getKeyParams(): EcdsaParams {
    return { name: 'ECDSA', hash: coseEllipticCurveNames[ECDSA.ellipticCurveKeys[this.algorithm]] };
}

private async toCOSE(key: CryptoKey): Promise<Map<number, any>> {
    const exportedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', key);
    const attData = new Map();
    attData.set(1, 2); // EC2 key type
    attData.set(3, this.algorithm);
    attData.set(-1, ECDSA.ellipticCurveKeys[this.algorithm]);
    attData.set(-2, base64ToByteArray(exportedKey.x, true));
    attData.set(-3, base64ToByteArray(exportedKey.y, true));
    return attData;
}
```

Comment: WebCrypto and Windows use P1363 format signature, while OpenSSL externally supports only the 'DER' (ASN.1) format. See dupes I previously listed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631148/im-trying-to-load-a-prime192v1-private-key-into-c-sharp-and-sign-some-data-im especially #39554165 which Stack already suggests autoatically at the right side of this page.

Comment: This issue needs more details and deeper investigation. You can e-mail to margus.pala@smartid.ee . I am sure I can help you with this issue.

Comment: Check if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885 helps you in your web authentication needs...